# Trying to get my image to fill the viewport using overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a `5000x3700` image that I'm using the overflow:hidden property on to get it to fill the viewport and not cause any scroll bars.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> Animations </title>
<style>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

.jumbotron1{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="books.jpeg" class="jumbotron1">
</body>
</html>
```

The above code doesn't do anything for me however. It just displays the full sized image with scroll bars. My problem is fixed if I remove the overflow property and just add width and height for the * element.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

My question is, why is overflow not working and why is the above addition of height and width working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why is overflow not working?

> The above code doesn't do anything for me however. It just displays the full sized image with scroll bars . . . my question is, why is overflow not working

*TL;DR Version: `overflow:hidden` is not causing the scrollbars, your image is full size and can't fit in the browser window, so the browser is adding the scrollbars.*

Actually, `overflow` is working exactly as expected. First, and this is really important to understand, setting `overflow:hidden` will cause content to be hidden when it is larger than the element's [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). Basically, if an element is within a box of a certain size, `overflow:hidden` will cause anything larger than the box to be clipped (or hidden from view)

Your initial code simply places the image on the page at full size. You have nothing constraining its size...

```
.jumbotron1 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Its parent elements (`body` and `html`) are also not constrained in size. The 'box' that your image is in is equal to its original size so there is nothing 'larger' than the box to be clipped - so you might expect no scrollbars. Indeed, `overflow:hidden` is actually ***not*** causing the scrollbars.

Really, your image *is* being clipped by the viewport (meaning the browser window) and that's why you are seeing scrollbars. Setting `overflow:hidden` will not resize the image to size of the viewport. If you had a gigantic monitor and your viewport was 5000px wide, then you would not see scrollbars.

---

### Why is the addition of height and width working?

*TL;DR Version: You've set every element to be the same dimensions as the viewport, so your image and browser window are now the same size - no scrollbars needed.*

Your additional  code sets the height and width of every element to full height and width of the root element (the `html` element). Since you have set no dimensions for the `html` element, it takes on the height and width of the viewport.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

In effect, you are setting the dimensions of your image to the same dimensions of the viewport. Since the image and the browser window are the same size, of course there will be no scrollbars.

I would not recommend using this as a fix to your problem. Using `*` will apply your style to every element in the document. That means all block level elements will also have `height:100%` and `width:100%`, so even a `<p>` element would literally cover your entire screen.

Plus, your image will not be proportionate. The height and width will both be based off of the browser window size, and you will end up with crazy image proportions like you can see here: https://codepen.io/noahjwhitmore/pen/rpZwyM

---

### Your Solution - vh Units

Setting an image height using `vh` units is going to solve your problem. Each `vh` unit represents 1% of the height of the viewport. So, applying `height:100vh' to your image should do the trick. If you put the image in the background of an element, you can even keep it centered.

```
.jumbotron1 {
    background-image: url('books.jpeg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    /* You may wish to un-comment the next
       property if you want the image to be
       the exact dimensions of the viewport */
    /* width: 100vw */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Really helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi will it be okay if you set the image as a background image?

If yes just add a background to body and set the height to 100 percent of your viewport.

```
body {
    background-image("books.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```